# How to minimize code in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, minimize

This may be a weird question, but i didnt find a solution for thiw anywhere. My question is simple, how can i minimize / optimalize code like this? Can this be done with some function or loop. I dont want to have like 500 lines in simple jQuery code like this.

```
var span1w = $("span", panel1).width();
var span2w = $("span", panel2).width();
var span3w = $("span", panel3).width();
var span4w = $("span", panel4).width();

var span1 = $("span", panel1);
var span2 = $("span", panel2);
var span3 = $("span", panel3);
var span4 = $("span", panel4);      

$(span1).css("margin-left", "-" + span1w / 2 + "px");
$(span2).css("margin-left", "-" + span2w / 2 + "px");
$(span3).css("margin-left", "-" + span3w / 2 + "px");
$(span4).css("margin-left", "-" + span4w / 2 + "px");
```

My HTML is just this with a bunch of JS under it. What im trying to do is center the **span** element by getting the width and using a simple css.

```
<body id="body">
    <img src="images/logos2.png" alt="KOP-KA logo Martin Mali" class="logo">
    <div id="web" class="uk-grid uk-width-1-1">
        <div class="uk-width-1-4" id="panel1">
            <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
            <span>SNAKE</span>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-1-4" id="panel2">
            <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
            <span>APP</span>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-1-4" id="panel3">
            <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
            <span>????</span>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-1-4" id="panel4">
            <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
            <span>O KOP</span>
        </div>           
    </div>
```

This is my CSS.

```
#panel1,#panel2,#panel3,#panel4{
    transition: background-color 0.6s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.6s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.6s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.6s linear;      
}

#panel2{
    border-left:1px solid rgba(32,145,216, 0.3);   
}
#panel3{
    border-left:1px solid rgba(32,145,216, 0.3);  
    border-right:1px solid rgba(32,145,216, 0.3);  
}
span{
    color:white;
    font-family:Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    font-size:60px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin: 0;
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

I really love fresh, fast and simple codes, that works well.

Comment: Show your HTML so that we can compare and minimize the code?

Comment: What are `panel1`, `panel2`, etc set to?

Comment: you gonna need to append these divs in a loop (<div class="uk-width-1-4" id="panel*") otherwise youll have 500 of those too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `.css()` callback function. The callback is called once for each element in the set. This means `css` iterates through the collection behind the scenes. Within the handler `this` keyword refers to the current element of iteration.

```
$('.uk-grid > div').find('span').css('margin-left', function() {
    return "-" + $(this).width() / 2 + "px";
});
```

Comment: This does work very well, thank you! Now iľl remember.